# How to correctly convert a unicode string to array of bytes in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having trouble with a conversion.  I'm using bcrypt with keyring to store and retrieve passwords.  However, keyring is giving me back a unicode string, but bcrypt needs an array of bytes.  I'm trying to use the best (most pythonic) way of converting the string that keyring is passing.

I have the following code sample:

```
password = b"super secret password"
hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt())
keyring.set_password("test_id", "user", hashed)
retrieved_pw = keyring.get_password("test_id", "user")
retrieved_pw2 = retrieved_pw.encode()
```

The PyCharm debugger shows the following types and values.  What I need to pass back to bcrypt is the duplicate of the variable, hashed.  When I try to use str.encode(), it seems to encapsulate the answer I need inside another string.  I've also tried using bytearray(), but that is basically a duplicate of str.encode()

> hashed:        {bytes 60} b'$2b$12$267Tbd09J5.BzST7XLS8OOKD9/ebKPIJyu.miCzi8571JrLXyYWnO'

> retrieved_pw:  {str} 'b'$2b$12$267Tbd09J5.BzST7XLS8OOKD9/ebKPIJyu.miCzi8571JrLXyYWnO''

> retrieved_pw2: {bytes 63} b"b'$2b$12$267Tbd09J5.BzST7XLS8OOKD9/ebKPIJyu.miCzi8571JrLXyYWnO'"

What is the best way to have retrieved_pw end up as a duplicate of hashed?

Comment: try `byte_pass = bytes(retrieved_pw,"utf8")`

Comment: `retrieved_pw = keyring.get_password("test_id", "user")[2:-1].encode()` or `keyring.set_password("test_id", "user", hashed.decode('utf-8'))`?

Comment: It looks like `keyring.set_password()` is converting to a string with `__str__` for `bytes` objects rather than using `bytes.decode()`. Your options look like they are to either strip the `b''` off (which the first method does) or just decode before you call `set_password` which the latter does.

Comment: Thanks a bunch guys.  Here's what I found: bytes(retreived_pw, "utf8"), gave the same result as bytearray().  Slicing the return string is the only method that worked.  I just think there's a more pythonic way to do this.  But for now the workable line is: ``` retreived_pw = keyring.get_password("test_id", "user")[2:-1].encode() ```